# Can the Android keyboard input be forced to display on the screen?

Tags: keyboard

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 (GT-N5110) tablet on Android 5.1.1.  want to force the Android keyboard input to be displayed on the screen. Previously, holding the menu button down brought the keyboard up in ScummVM, but now it tries to open a search app.

I have changed the action to nothing, but all that happens is the ScummVM input window loses focus when I hold down the menu key.

Can the Android keyboard input be forced to display on the screen?

Comment: I think this is what I wanted to achieve: [Is there any way to manually bring up the keyboard?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/is-there-any-way-to-manually-bring-up-the-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

ScummVM (2.0.0) in particular has its own keyboard which you can access by tapping the button in the top left corner.