# Keeping Gboard open while multitasking

Tags: gboard, popup, multitasking, multi-window

I'm using an Android 10 Samsung device that supports multitasking using pop-up windows. I'm trying to type on the main window with a YouTube window in the foreground. The keyboard keeps closing whenever I use the YouTube pop-up. Is there any way to keep it open?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is a way.. but even if you have your keyboard always open, you'll have to press on the text box of the other app after using youtube to bring it in focus.

If you still want to have it opened always then you can use "Automate" app..
Just set a gesture(quick tiles or button combination) to trigger the "always on keyboard" and set the action..
Comment if you have any doubt..

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way without a third-party app, though?

Comment: With gboard? I don't think so.. There are other keyboards which offer this feature but then you'll lack the cool functions of gboard..

Comment: Which keyboard offer that functionality?

Comment: Do you have a link to that automate app?

Comment: @Slion I don't remember which keyboards I was talking about (hacker's keyboard maybe, not sure). It's been 3 yrs. Anyway, here's the Automate app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate

Comment: Thanks, though I can't find that always on keyboard action.

Comment: @Slion use ADB shell command action, `adb shell input keyevent 108` [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68715061/14276580). There's a lot to play around in that app. Also, check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/is-there-any-way-to-manually-bring-up-the-keyboard) for Hacker's keyboard thing. If it was helpful, an upvote would be great.