# Is there any way to force opening a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I've recently bought Lenovo Tab M9 tablet. Unfortunately on one of the websites I frequently use, the keyboard doesn't show in a field I need to type. Is there any way to force opening virtual keyboard to be able to type? I would prefer not use a psychical one. The suggestion from [this old question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/is-there-any-way-to-manually-bring-up-the-keyboard) is no longer available.

Comment: Which "suggestion" are you referring to, the linked question has multiple answers?